# Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead when closing the browser/tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, express.io

im writing my first chat app in nodejs , my app basically keeps track of online users and put them in the rooms to chat via webrtc ...im using pm2 to run the chat server

so i noticed sometimes when i close browser tabs my app will crash and pm2 will reload the server so i checked the log and saw this error

```
0|chat  | Error: read ECONNRESET
0|chat  |     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
0|chat  |   errno: -104,
0|chat  |   code: 'ECONNRESET',
0|chat  |   syscall: 'read'
0|chat  | }
```

here is the error when runing withouth pm2

```
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

to make sure it's not my code causing this error i removed all the codes in my app and just put 2 simple function to listen to online(called by online client via socket.io) and disconnect(called automatically by user disconnect ) events ... and sure enough after closing and opening some tabs it happen again here is simplified version of my code

im using `Express.io` which is a combination of Express and Socket.io

```
const  env = require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' })
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

app = require('express.io')();

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync( env.parsed.SSL_KEY),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(env.parsed.SSL_CERT)
};
app.https(options).io();
console.log('|-> protocol : https ');



app.io.route('online' , function (req){
    console.log(`| online socket -> ${req.socket.id}`);
})


app.io.route('disconnect', function(req) {
    console.log(`|->****************** disconnect : ${req.socket.id}`);
});

var PORT = env.parsed.PORT  || 8080
console.log(`|-> listining to port ${PORT} `);
app.listen(PORT );
```

i've searched online and know why it's happening (i think) but i dont have any data communication in this code it  .... i've no idea how to handle this and appreciate any help

here is the complete log you can see it happening after closing some tabs

[image]

```
/root/.pm2/logs/chat-out.log last 15 lines:
0|chat     | |-> protocol : https
0|chat     | |-> listining to port 8080

/root/.pm2/logs/chat-error.log last 15 lines:
0|chat     | (node:19821) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
0|chat     | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

0|chat  | | online socket -> Z2z7m6D9OXKPGRVhbz4R
0|chat  | |->****************** disconnect : H_1-d7sIm2oIvxzzbz4Q
0|chat  | | online socket -> JrnLWbqN4luBtYg4bz4S
0|chat  | | online socket -> ZSY1wIywMEdmUcALbz4T
0|chat  | | online socket -> ugSg08DksJ73ld1Rbz4U
0|chat  | |->****************** disconnect : ugSg08DksJ73ld1Rbz4U
0|chat  | |->****************** disconnect : ZSY1wIywMEdmUcALbz4T
0|chat  | Error: read ECONNRESET
0|chat  |     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
0|chat  |   errno: -104,
0|chat  |   code: 'ECONNRESET',
0|chat  |   syscall: 'read'
0|chat  | }
PM2     | App [chat:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2     | App [chat:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2     | App [chat:0] online
0|chat  | |-> protocol : https
0|chat  | |-> listining to port 8080
0|chat  | (node:19864) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
0|chat  | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Comment: The npm package `express.io` has not been updated in last 8 years, and it was supposed to work with node v5. My best advice would be to use socket.io on a express project.

Comment: What nodejs version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out the problem without seeing the client code but my bet is by declaring this route

```
app.io.route('disconnect', function(req) {
    console.log(`|->****************** disconnect : ${req.socket.id}`);
});
```

you are misusing the `express.io` library:

https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/lib#reserved-events

> These events are reserved and should not be used with `app.io.route` or `req.io.on` unless you know what you are doing.
>
> - connect
> - connecting
> - disconnect
> - connect_failed
> - error
> - message
> - reconnect_failed
> - reconnect
> - reconnecting

BTW like another comment said, this library is old and you should not use it. It uses Socket.IO v0.9 and the current version is v4.